# Subset a nested list to get all the lower level lists with the same characters in their names

Tags: r, list, subset, nested-lists

UPDATE:
Combining the 2 suggestions in the comments, I got

```
dlist4[contains("M", names(dlist4))]
Error:
! `contains()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

or

```
dlist4 %>%select.list(., contains(names(.), "M"))
1: list(a = 1:4, b = 2:5)
2: list(a = 10:13, b = 5:8)
3: list(a = 10:13, b = 5:8)
4: list(a = 2:5, b = 5:8)

Selection:
```

or

```
dlist4 %>% select(contains(names(.), "M"))
Error in `select()`:
! `select()` doesn't handle lists.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I'd like to extract all the nested lists with `M_` in their names and save them to a new list without typing out the specific item.

```
dput(dlist4)
list(A = list(a = structure(1:4, dim = c(2L, 2L)), b = structure(2:5, dim = c(2L, 
2L))), G = list(a = structure(10:13, dim = c(2L, 2L)), b = structure(5:8, dim = c(2L, 
2L))), M_1 = list(a = structure(10:13, dim = c(2L, 2L)), b = structure(5:8, dim = c(2L, 
2L))), M_2 = list(a = structure(2:5, dim = c(2L, 2L)), b = structure(5:8, dim = c(2L, 
2L))))
```

For this small list, I can do `dlist4[c("M_1", "M_2")]`, but imagining a larger nested list with hundreds of lower level lists whose names **either contain or start with "M_"**. Then, typing them all out would not be possible.

`dlist4 %>% pluck("M_")` gives `NULL` with no error so I don't know what's wrong with my code.

`dlist4 %>% map(., ~{pluck("M_")})` returns an empty list and picks the wrong elements (A and G)

```
$A
[1] "M_"

$G
[1] "M_"

$M_1
[1] "M_"

$M_2
[1] "M_"
```

Comment: `dlist4 %>% keep(startsWith(names(.), "M_"))`

Comment: `dlist4[grep("^M_", names(dlist4))]`